# Question about notation - the differential

Tags: differential-geometry, derivatives, physics, infinitesimals

In physics it is usually denote $dx^i$ by an "infinitesimal" variation of the variable $x^i$, and for example, the work could be written as:
$$\delta W=\sum_i Y^i dx^i$$
(1) This implies that in sense $\delta W$ is a 1-form?

(2) How is the conceptual relation between an "infinitesimal" variation of $x^i$ and the differential of the coorditate $x^i$?

Many thanks!

Comment: If you are envisioning the $x^i$ as being coordinates on the manifold, then the $\mathrm{d}x^i$ are coordinates on the tangent space.
(and it can be fruitful to envision the points of the tangent space at $P$ as being a collection of points infinitesimally close to $P$)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, *yes* $dW$ is a $1$-form based on this definition $dW = \sum Y^i\,dx^i$. The idea is that $dW$ itself is something to be integrated to find the total work $W = \int dW = \int\sum Y^i\,dx^i$.

To understand the conceptual relation between an infinitesimal variation of $x^i$ and the $1$-form $dx^i$, consider as in single-variable integration the object $dx$ as "a small change in $x$". In terms of work and forces, $dx$ is a small displacement of the particle, say. Hence, $W = \int dW = \int F\,dx$.

In the multivariable setting the idea is the same in that each of the $dx^i$ accounts for "small displacements" in each direction so that
$$
W = \int dW = \int \sum Y^i\,dx^i.
$$